# How to find details related to the running windows apps using Powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-8, windows-store-apps, powershell-3.0

Currently, I am working on the task that nrequires the running windows apps details using powershell script.
I found pointers in this regard that can give me the "Process" on which all the windows apps are getting hosted while they are running.
More specifically - I can understand that when any windows app runs on "**Windows 8**" machine it gets hosted to the process named - **WWAHost.exe** .

Now, I need to find out its in depth detail such as "App name", how we can get that using powershell script?
I tried with *Get-Process* & *Get-Member* commands but those seems to be not helpful to get the actual app name (or  might be i am missing something while scripting these commands).
Some pointers on this would be really helpful. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you run:

`Get-Process | FT -Autosize`

This will give you the processes that are running, and put them in a table format.

Answer (score 0):

```
[prompt] $procs = Get-WMIObject win32_process  
[prompt] $procs[0] | Get-Member
```

You will find properties such as Name, CommandLine, ExecutablePath, etc.
Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, but though it gives me Name,Commandline etc I would like to find the exact "Name" of the running App, would it be possible? For example below is the code with output :PS C:\Windows\system32> $procs[0] | Get-Member Name


   TypeName: System.Management.ManagementObject#root\cimv2\Win32_Process

Name MemberType Definition
---- ---------- ----------
Name Property   string Name {get;set;} . Now I wonder how to get the "Name" if this command just gives me its definition?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "exact 'Name' of the running App" -- what information do you need that Get-Process and Get-WMIObject can't provide?  Get-Process->Name returns "EXCEL" for that application, while Get-WMIObject->Caption returns EXCEL.EXE, Get->WMIObject->ExecutablePath returns "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14\EXCEL.EXE", and so on.  What, specifically, are you looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The way I read this is that you are running a PowerShell cmdlet.

`[prompt] $procs = Get-WMIObject win32_process`

`[prompt] $procs[0] | Get-Member`

This will not return the process. What this will return the following:

The following is an error; that states that PowerShell does not know what to do with '[prompt]'

> Unable to find type [prompt]. Make sure that the assembly that contains this type is loaded.
>   At line:2 char:1
>   + [prompt] $procs[0] | Get-Member
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (prompt:TypeName) [], RuntimeException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : TypeNotFound

I think what you want it is something like this:

`$procs = Get-WMIObject win32_process`

`$procs[0]`

This will give you the first process that returns from the Cmdlet that is ran. I hope this helps.